# In OpenApi Spring code generation, singleContentTypes is set to True but is not working

Tags: spring, maven, openapi, openapi-generator

As the title says, I am trying to generate code for **Spring** using **OpenApi** and i have the following plugin in my backend **pom.xml**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/endpoints.yaml</inputSpec>
                <generatorName>spring</generatorName>
                <configOptions>
                    <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                    <singleContentTypes>true</singleContentTypes>
                </configOptions>
                <apiPackage>com.adesso.freeseek.web.api</apiPackage>
                <modelPackage>com.adesso.freeseek.web.model</modelPackage>
                <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/openapi</output>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and this is my **endpoints.yaml** file

```
openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: game API v1
  description: |
    F
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: http://localhost:8080
tags:
  - name: game
paths:
  /login:
    post:
      summary: User login
      operationId: login
      tags:
        - Login
      requestBody:
        required: true
        content:
          application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
            schema:
              type: object
              required: ["username", "password"]
              properties:
                username:
                  type: string
                  example: user
                password:
                  type: string
                  example: password1234
      security: []
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
          headers:
            Set-Cookie:
              schema:
                type: string
                example: JSESSIONID=abcde12345; Path=/; HttpOnly
        "403":
          description: "Unauthorized"
  /logout:
    post:
      security:
        - cookieAuth: []
      summary: User logout
      operationId: logout
      tags:
        - Login
      responses:
        "200":
          description: "OK"
        "500":
          description: "Something went wrong"
```

The Problem is that its creating two interfaces which are `web\api\LoginApi.java` and `web\api\LogoutApi.java` so the **singleContentTypes** is not working. I want all generated methods to be in one interface

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to have both endpoints contained within a single api.  This can be accomplished using the [`useTags`](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/#:%7E:text=true-,useTags,-use%20tags%20for) configuration option.

Try adding the `useTags` to your configuration like this:

```xml
<configOptions>
  <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
  <singleContentTypes>true</singleContentTypes>
  <useTags>true</useTags>
</configOptions>
```

This will result in a single api called `LoginApi` with both the login and logout endpoints within it.